# ARKit 3D Modell is without Textures

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, arkit

I've imported an .dae model without textures and then added every texture for every node (part) in xCode:

[image]

Then I've created an .scn scene where I added the car:

[image]

And this is how I call it:

```
     guard let shipScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/CarScene.scn") else {
        return
    }
    guard let shipNode = shipScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "car reference", recursively: false) else {
        return
    }
```

Does anybody have an idea, why I'm not getting the textures shown?

Btw. the textures are .BMP which I dragged on the Diffuse Property

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem:

Check that the file (BMP or whatever) is in your project file and then add it to the materials Diffuse Attribute. Mine wasn't in my project that's why it wasn't showing on the phone but on the editor.